# How is this the correct answer in this number sequence?

Tags: number-sequence, explanation

I have this sequence:

> 24, 63, 10, 48, 35, 72, 44....

The next number is

> 80.

How is this the correct answer?

Comment: All of those are composite numbers: 4x6, 7x9, 2x5, 6x8, 5x7, 8x9, 4x11 (and also 8x10). That might have something to do with it.

Comment: More than that: most of them are of the form n^2-1. *25*, *64*, 11, *49*, *36*, 73, 45, *81*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible answer that works for finding the next number, but not the entire sequence is

> The number sequence is generated in pairs with a descending sum
>  24 + **39** = 63
>  10 + **38** = 48
>  35 + **37** = 72

This would imply the next number in the sequence is

> 44 + 36 = **80**